# Word meaning "difficult to eliminate"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'd like to express that I went to great efforts to fix an [adjective] bug in my code. Neither "pernicious" nor "persistent" quite match the quality I'm trying to describe. Is there a word that means "hard to eradicate" but not necessarily that the problem itself was severe? The problems caused by the bug were fairly insignificant, but fixing it was a huge pain.

Comment: I like to say a problem has *metastasized*.

Comment: "Unflushable" coupling wisdom :-)

Comment: 'persistent' doesn't connote severity, what's wrong with it?

Comment: A persistent bug sounds to me like a bug that has existed for a long time without necessarily resisting efforts to eliminate it. Perhaps it is the most appropriate term though.

Comment: hard-**bit**ten? :)

Comment: I also like what Stephen Hawking said about time, that it is a "stubbornly persistent illusion."

Comment: I was going to say "constipated" but I guess that's not quite right.

Comment: Would *wedged* do? Not necessarily the bug was damaging but it was dam difficult to remove. (I won't post it as an answer 'cos I ain't a computer programmer.)

Comment: If you want to be creative, you could call it a "Rasputin bug". Grigori Rasputin is perceived by westerners as having been extraordinarily hard to kill http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigori_Rasputin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could say: "I went to great efforts to fix a **stubborn** bug in my code."

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Astubborn&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) defines stubborn as:

> difficult to move, remove, or cure.

Comment: Stubborn sounds the best to me in this context, and that definition is perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

### [Tenacious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tenacious):

1. holding fast; characterized by keeping a firm hold (often followed by of):

   - a tenacious grip on my arm; tenacious of old habits.
2. highly retentive:

   - a tenacious memory.
3. pertinacious, persistent, stubborn, or obstinate.

"I went to great efforts to fix a tenacious bug in my code."

Comment: Also _persistent._

Comment: @JohnLawler OP specifically said he wasn't looking for *persistent*.

Comment: OP's preference has nothing to do with the meaning of _persistent_ in this context.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't disagree with you. Just pointing out that the word has already been mentioned.

Comment: If we keep it up, *persistent* will never go away.

Answer (score 5):

**Obstinate** is a good word for this, as it describes something that is undesirable and persistent. From [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obstinate):

> 1. firmly or stubbornly adhering to one's purpose, opinion, etc.; not yielding to argument, persuasion, or entreaty.
> 2. characterized by inflexible persistence or an unyielding attitude; inflexibly persisted in or carried out: obstinate advocacy of high tariffs.
> 3. not easily controlled or overcome: the obstinate growth of weeds.
> 4. not yielding readily to treatment, as a disease.

If you want a $2 metaphor, you can try **Obdurate** ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obdurate)):

> 1. unmoved by persuasion, pity, or tender feelings; stubborn; unyielding.
> 2. stubbornly resistant to moral influence; persistently impenitent:
>      an obdurate sinner.

Answer (score 5):

**Intractable** is my favourite for this sort of thing; not hard, but annoying and difficult to get to grips with.

Answer (score 4):

**Resilient** would be appropriate.

From Merriam-Webster:

```
:  characterized or marked by resilience: as
a :  capable of withstanding shock without permanent deformation or rupture
b :  tending to recover from or adjust easily to misfortune or change
```

Definition 'b' seems especially apt.

In science and medicine literature people often talk about bacteria (something undesirable, like a computer bug) being resilient to efforts used to try and eradicate it.

Comment: "Resilient bug" is quite close to an oxymoron

Comment: @zimbra314 Do you think so? I know that if I have to debug code and it seems like I'm straightening up every line, and making all kinds of changes, and yet the bug remains I would consider that resilient. But in the sense of computer security, I can see what you mean by a bug maybe being oxymoronic.

Comment: My area happens to be fault tolerant/resilient computing( which certainly doesn't give me authority over usage of the word resilient). I, therefore, feel a positive connotation attached with the word resilient. Thus, I see an absurdity in the term "Resilient bug"

Answer (score 3):

When I have longstanding bugs in my code they end up **entrenched** in all sorts of different processes.

[Oxford Dictionaries, entrench](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/entrench):

> 1 [with object] Establish (an attitude, habit, or belief) so firmly that change is very difficult or unlikely: 'ageism is entrenched in our society'

Answer (score 1):

Programming bugs and math problems can be **recalcitrant**, at times.  The word comes from a root calc-, calx heel (of a donkey or horse, for example).  Thus, a stubborn problem that 'kicks back'.  I first heard this from an MIT math prof describing a type of differential equation, and merriam-webster led me to the definition ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use **entangled** or **defiant**, if you're in to anthropomorphizing. I also second **obstinate**.